# to paint someone (other than oneself) "into a corner"

Tags: idioms-in-context

Do these 3 sentences properly use the idiom "paint someone into a corner"? Or can it only be used as "paint oneself into a corner" (i.e., it wouldn't be possible to paint *someone else* into a corner)?

> They were painted into a corner.

> They were painted into a corner by the situation.

> Their colleagues painted them into a corner.

The meaning I was intending to convey would be that they were [put in a bind](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/293728/229087) by someone else. Most dictionary entries only talk about painting *oneself* into a corner.

Comment: It's nearly always used reflexively, and given it's a somewhat "quaint" usage, the last thing you'd want to do as a non-native speaker would be to "experiment" with variations to the idiomatic standard. Remember that the primary allusion of the usage is similar to *hoist by one's own petard, nailing one's colours to the mast, running up a gum tree,* etc. (usually, worsening your own circumstances by lack of forethought). It doesn't sit well with ***other people*** "boxing you in" to a potentially indefensible position.

Comment: Per @FumbleFingers’ comment, part of the expression’s connotational impact is the irony of having done it to oneself. So I could add to his list of similar images *shoot oneself in the foot*.

Comment: By the same token,you should also avoid *...sawing the branch you're sitting on*.

Comment: Please look at all the examples in my answer: paint oneself into a corner OR paint [someone] into a corner are both idiomatic, as shown by many newspaper quotations on ludwig.guru

Comment: And it is true that **India's finance ministers have been painted into a corner** by their predecessors because of the cost of financing the deficit. **The Economist**, which has the best English in the entire world...

Answer (score 7):

You can only paint someone else into a corner if they're holding your paint pot ;)

To paint yourself into a corner is to, *by your own action*, make it impossible to get out of a difficult situation, which gets worse with every further action you take… unless you walk over the floor you've just been painting.

The analogy is to a literal situation - you enter a room with a single door, turn round & start painting the floor. Each brush stroke moves you further from the doorway, until you have only the farthest corner to stand in. You could be standing there on your own, or with a team of like-minded painters, making it a collaborative action that gets you there.

To answer the question as asked - no, you cannot be painted into a corner by someone else's action, only your own.

*From comments.*
The thing that distinguishes this from similar phrases - hoist by one's own petard; shoot oneself in the foot etc., is that to paint yourself into a corner is not the result of a *single action* but multiple actions, each increasing your distance from 'the door'.

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit I never realised ***why*** we say/said this! Obvious once you point it out, but that just goes to show how easily native speaker ignore *literal* meanings when it comes to idiomatic usages!

Comment: They really painted us into a corner with their cogent arguements.

Comment: @Lambie - then they were standing in the paint.

Comment: Yes, but the metaphor works anyway.

Comment: @Lambie - not for me. It sounds like someone who didn't understand what the original meaning was, & extemporised.

Comment: They would have to start at the corner and you'd have to be already standing in the corner, and they would be backing away from you as they painted. In which case you wouldn't have been *painted into* the corner. You cannot put someone *into* a jail cell  who is already in the jail cell. Same with "backed me into a corner".  That can't happen if you start out in the corner.

Comment: You can stand at a point where there are two people in a corner, with a bucket of paint in your hand, and start painting an arc around them and move backward from there and you would never be standing in the paint...the paint area would be between you and the people in the corner and it could get bigger as you move away from them.

Comment: @Lambie - that seems to be exactly what TimR said, but making the opposite argument.

Comment: "To answer the question as asked - no, you cannot be painted into a corner by someone else's action, only your own." That is not accurate.  See Ludwig.guru for loads of examples: https://app.ludwig.guru/s/paint+into+a+corner One example: The players are now painted into a corner, with two unpalatable offers and the threat of a canceled season. New York Times from that site.

Comment: Requires sign-up. Of all the sources I've checked, only one [freedictionary] allows it to be done by someone else. I still maintain that is erroneous usage, probably caused by not understanding the original meaning.

Comment: @Lambie - Keeping on insisting you are right & I am wrong just gets tiring after a while. Your own answer insisting it can be applicable doesn't seem to be faring so well; nor are any of those downvotes mine. Boxing into a corner is precisely the opposite - that is always forced by someone else. It's from boxing, the sport, & is not related to the painting scenario at all. 'Up against the ropes' is another in the same vein.

Answer (score 1):

**to paint *oneself* into a corner** *is the idiomatic expression.*
**To paint [x] into a corner** *is also an idiomatic expression.*

BUT: They painted us into a corner. That works too.

He painted me into a corner. Just two examples.

From that we get:
They painted themselves into a corner.
He painted himself into a corner.
She painted herself into a corner.
I painted myself into a corner.
We painted  ourselves into a corner.
You painted  yourself into a corner.

Just follow the idiom.

Also: others can paint you into a corner:

> Should Republicans actually **try to paint Democrats into a corner**
> with a rapid repeal, Reid painted a bleak picture of the ensuing
> damage. The Huffington Post
>
> He was obviously more focused on creating a framework that's open to
> certain precedent — an album like Herbie Hancock's "Prisoner" comes to
> mind — **but doesn't feel painted into a corner.** The New York Times
>
> Brian Bacchus, who produced "Liquid Spirit" and has also collaborated
> with Norah Jones and Cassandra Wilson, described this expansive work
> as a response to "the jazz singer **having been painted into a corner in
> terms of the repertoire**," much of which is now considerably older than
> many of its interpreters. The Los Angeles Times

[paint into a corner from Ludwig.guru](https://app.ludwig.guru/s/to+paint+into+a+corner)

> Warning that the **prime minister’s actions since the election have
> painted him into a corner as his self-imposed 31 December deadline for
> a deal grows nearer, the ex-minister said**: “The question really is
> whether Boris prefers to wreck the economy by going along with his
> backbenchers and going for no deal – or the Australia option as he’s
> now calling it – with all the disruption to trade and price hikes and
> business closures and job losses that would mean, not to mention going
> down in history as the Tory PM who broke up the union.

[The Independent_UK](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/boris-johnson-brexit-eu-trade-deal-eu-alignment-remain-a9336196.html)

> Second, this book will help young women see the importance of
> partnering with their parents in the courtship process. I believe most
> young women want their parents involved in this. **Of course, the
> culture has painted them into a corner, and they don’t quite know how
> to get out**.

[Book_UK](https://Second,%20this%20book%20will%20help%20young%20women%20see%20the%20importance%20of%20partnering%20with%20their%20parents%20in%20the%20courtship%20process.%20I%20believe%20most%20young%20women%20want%20their%20parents%20involved%20in%20this.%20Of%20course,%20the%20culture%20has%20painted%20them%20into%20a%20corner,%20and%20they%20don%E2%80%99t%20quite%20know%20how%20to%20get%20out.)

And from The Economist via Ludwig.guru, also:

> And it is true that **India's finance ministers have been painted into
> a corner** by their predecessors because of the cost of financing the
> deficit.

**The Economist** has the best English in the entire world...

Comment: downvoter: tsk, tsk, tsk. My answer shows where this goes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I realized my question wasn't as clear as it should be, my worry was whether someone could paint *someone else* into a corner. Your answer and the other ones made it clear that no, it should always be used reflexively. I'll edit my question to improve clarity

Comment: @flen "He really painted me into a corner". What is odd in yours is the passive.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! But now I'm confused, the other answer seems to contradict this and claim "They painted us into a corner" wouldn't be correct

Comment: @flen Go take a look at my link from ludwig.guru. There are lots of examples. The other answer re the pot is a literal interpretation and not a metaphorical one...

Comment: I don't find the first example a particularly good usage of the idiom, and in the second and third examples, the person painted into the corner is indeed complicit in their own fate - the passages refer to musicians being artistically limited by the genres and styles they themselves choose to play. In the second example, Clayton does not feel painted in by his own choice of respecting precedent, and in the third, the jazz singer is painted in by their own representation of the genre. These aren't purely external limitations, and do have an aspect of painting oneself in.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie but then I agree with Lambie, it *is* possible to be painted into a corner by someone else (albeit in collaboration with oneself). Though I also agree with the broader point that I've heard of people "being painted into a corner" by others. Whether they employed the idiom correctly is up for dispute

Comment: @flen You can paint yourself into a corner or someone can paint you into a corner. Both are fine.//I meant: Who is Clayton??

Comment: @Lambie I think NuclearHoagie googled the 2nd sentence example and landed on its original page: https://www.nytimes.com/2012/09/29/arts/music/gerald-clayton-sextet-at-jazz-standard.html the subject there is the pianist Gerald Clayton

Comment: @Lambie Your second example comes from an article about a jazz musician named Clayton, and the sentence you've used describes whether he feels limited *by his own choice of style*. The context is pretty important, there is no one limiting this person other than themselves - they haven't been painted in by anyone.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie None of those examples are my sentences. They are all taken from well-known news publications.

Comment: @Lambie My quibble isn't with who wrote it, it's that they're not good examples of someone painting someone else into a corner.

Comment: The New  York Times, The Los Angeles Times, The Guardian, TechCrunch and Vice all use paint into a corner. You can check for yourselves at: https://app.ludwig.guru/s/paint+into+a+corner

Comment: @Lambie - _And if Rose has painted him into a corner with her scheming, this shatters the last weak plank beneath him._- maybe this idiom pudding is a bit rich in a metaphor, but it's in the Los Angeles Review of Books. The law about informal idioms is notoriously vague, and I thoroughly agree with your position.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well, I always feel like I hit the jackpot when I see that The Economist agrees with me. [chuckle]. Interesting quote you give where the word if is not really if, but that's another story. :)

Comment: New York Times 2 Apr 1986 — _In a sense, they painted him into a corner out of which he could extricate himself only through efficient management._ Personally, I'd prefer 'from which', but we're in informal territory, so it's OK.

Comment: Also the _Wall Street Journal_ and the _Texas Tribune_.

Comment: @Lambie above, I meant to type 'a bit rich in metaphor' but you get the idea?

Comment: Upvote from me. While the usage of painting someone else into a corner is clearly a corruption of the original idiom, it's one that is commonly attested in reputable sources and easily understood by native speakers

Comment: This is a high quality, well researched answer. I happen to agree with most others that the expression can only be used reflexively, and that any other use is a misuse. This may slip past even the best editor, but if it made it past the editors of all those highly reputable publications, I've got no leg to stand on. I will still teach my students only to use it reflexively, but this answer gets a +1.

Comment: @gotube Thanks for that. It occurs to me that we say: patoneself on the back but we also pat others on the back. I just don't get why this became such a big deal....at least I'm out of minus point territory.

Comment: @Lambie My guess is it went south because most people share my opinion, and wouldn't hear anything different, even if it was evidence-backed. Such is the human condition.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the idiom of painting yourself into a corner is very much about making avoidable errors that put yourself in a difficult position. It's not something you can do to others.

But you can "back someone into a corner" or "put someone in a corner". That means to put the other person into a difficult position. It sometimes, but not always, is used to imply that the person might have to take extreme or violent measures to resolve the situation (similar to "having your back to the wall").

Comment: So all these are wrong? https://app.ludwig.guru/s/paint+into+a+corner And it is true that **India's finance ministers have been painted into a corner** by their predecessors because of the cost of financing the deficit. **The Economist**, which has the best English in the entire world...

Comment: @Lambie, your link seems to require a login, and I don't have one for that site.

Comment: Well, then, just believe me if you don't want to sign up. It's a much better resource than anything else, pretty much. I recommend it. I just don't think one can argue with The Economist.

Comment: I say again. You can paint _someone else_ into a corner. And they can do it to you.